# Creating a black and white grid HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a 3 by 3 black and white grid. But instead only black square is showing. I have tried using Bootstrap.

My one square of the grid should cover 3 grids space as per bootstrap grid system and I am using `padding-top:100%` to maintain the aspect ratio for the squares in the 3 by 3 grid.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: pink;
}

.square {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.square-w {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-3 ">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-3 ">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-3">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The demo above does have white and black squares. The only issues I see is that you probably don't want the left/right padding that is there between squares and that you might want to use `col-md-4` if you want to fill up the whole grid as there's 12 columns. There's also the possibility that you need to use a smaller column class.

Comment: Maybe you could find some inspiration here: [Chessboard with pieces using pure HTML and CSS](http://code2care.org/pages/chessboard-with-pieces-using-pure-html-and-css/)

Comment: Okay, but yours extends for 9 columns. Are you sure you're using the correct column class size? How large is the screen you're working on?

Comment: Actually I am quite intrigued , for why my code doesn't work.

Comment: yeah  9 col , made error before

Comment: @Dodo, you can edit your comments for up to five minutes instead of making a million replies.

Comment: it will work as it should, but only for screen width ≥768px, because you defined col-md-3 for all divs [maybe check this table](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen view might be too small.
Changing all the `col-md-3` classes to `col-sm-3` allows it to be shown on my view

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2k5523ym/1/

Comment: I did view it in laptop, but still only one square was visible.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put below code in css

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

and then assign nopadding class to every col-md-3 div

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square-w"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Hope this help you